# convexity of piece wise function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a piece-wise function defined on the real line. The pieces are connected continuously, and the second derivative of each piece is strictly positive. Does this means that the function is convex?

More generally, where can I see about properties of such function or such construction?

Comment: Adding the condition that each piece is monotonic increasing. Is there another condition that would prove convexity? increasing of the second derivative?

Comment: monotonicity won't help either, see edits to my answer.

Comment: I think you need to ensure that the gradient of the overall piece-wise function is monotonically increasing. Just think about the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you function can be non-convex as a whole. Take for example $$f(x) = \begin{cases}(x-1)^2,&x\ge 0,\\(x+1)^2,&x<0.\end{cases}.$$

It has convex pieces, yet globally it is neither convex nor concave.

**edit**

Moreover, you proposed condition that the function is increasing doesn't help, either. Take $$g(x) = \begin{cases}x^2+1,&x\ge 0,\\e^{x},&x<0.\end{cases}.$$

Comment: We must have been typing at the same time.

Comment: @coffeemath and I was typing a similar comment to your answer=)

Comment: Your second function is not increasing, but I think that can be rectified.

Comment: @MichaelGrant oops, nice catch. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ if $x \ge 0$ and $(x+1)^2$ if $x<0$ is not convex, but the two pieces are continuously connected (at $(0,1)$) and each has strictly positive second derivative, namely $2.$